# CORS only fails when requesting from NextJS front-end app

Tags: .net, kubernetes, next.js

I have a kubernetes cluster with a NextJS app and a dotnet service. When making requests from the front-end to the service only those of type 'GET' work. On others I get a CORS fail on method OPTIONS.

I created another deployment to test the service with curl and to my surprise it works.

Why does this happen? If I get a CORS error when fetching from the nextjs front deployment, why don't I get the same error when fetching from another deployment in the same cluster?

I'm making the requests (except the ones with 'GET' method) from a client-side page on NextJS, since I need to use onclick and onsubmit